# Esri uniform meters grid to geographical coordinates

Tags: coordinate-system

I have a bathymetry for which I have a grid file:

```
Projection    MERCATOR
Datum         WGS84
Spheroid      WGS84
Units         METERS
Zunits        NO
Xshift        0.0
Yshift        0.0
Parameters    
 100  0  0.0 /* longitude of central meridian
 -41  0  0.0 /* latitude of true scale
0.0 /* false easting (meters)
0.0 /* false northing (meters)
```

and a bathymetry file itself:

```
ncols 12116 
nrows 15391 
xllcorner 4795705.6 
yllcorner -5915585.8
cellsize 250 
NODATA_value -9999
```

I understand that 250 m grid is valid only for -41 latitude of true scale, so I need to scale for other latitudes. However, I don't understand what means xllcorner/yllcorner in this case. How can I convert them to latitude and longitude to use as a reference point? Longitude of central meridian (100deg) doesn't seem to be what I need, because the bathymetry is for New Zealand.

Comment: So, is this a raster file, or a vector file? What CRS is being used?

Comment: I may provide a link: https://niwa.co.nz/our-science/oceans/bathymetry/download-the-data?sid=21923 . I use NZ 250m ESRI ASCII grid

Comment: "Scaling" would include interpolation of the grid, thus leading to warping the data. Also, you need to know which CRS the data is in, in order to "understand" the corner coordinates.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try first to ask for CRS...

Comment: Acoording to the website, the data is in [EPSG 3994](https://epsg.io/3994) (WGS 84 / Mercator 41)

Comment: Thanks! I was not able to find that page. According to it, the covering region is [-60:-25, 155:-170], so supposedly I can adapt  xllcorner/yllcorner from this information. Is there a tool to accurately recalculate coordinates for WGS84 (unfortunatelly I don't have any)? I suppose just recalculating longitudes at each latitude as: (250mINdegree)/cos(latitude) is not so accurate...

Comment: Indeed, the formulae to convert to Lat/Lon are more complex. But what do you intend to do with the data? Which software do you plan to use? Lots of software and libraries already exist to analyse and reproject datasets, QGIS, GRASS, r, ArcGIS, GDAL, etc.

Comment: I plan to use it in my model for tsunami simulation to which I may use this bathymetry as input only with latitude/longitude...